# Prove limit using epsilon-delta definition

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

How do you prove this using the epsilon-delta definition? I'm unsure of using the min = { } function.

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{2x+1}{1-x}$

These are my steps:

$ |f(x) - L| < \epsilon => |\frac{2x+1}{1-x} +2|< \epsilon $

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; \; \; \; =>|\frac{3}{1-x} | < \epsilon $

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; \; \; \; =>|\frac{-3}{x-1} | < \epsilon$

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; \; \; \; =>|-3||\frac{1}{x-1} | < \epsilon$

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; \; \; \; =>|\frac{1}{x-1} | < \frac{\epsilon}{3}$

$ \qquad \qquad \; \; \; \; \; =>|{x-1} | < \frac{\epsilon |x-1|}{3}$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: I got stuck at |1/(1-x)|<ε, I can't figure how to achieve |x-a|<δ

Comment: Achieve $|x-a| < \delta $? How are you approaching this?

Comment: |f(x) - L| < ε => |x-1| < ε|x-1|/3

Answer (score 2):

A few pointers:

- The $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of a limit pertains to when you have a limit as $x \to a$, where $a$ is a finite quantity. For a limit as $x \to \infty$, you need an $\varepsilon$-$M$ definition, along the lines of, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists some $M$ such that
  $$x > M \implies |f(x) - L| < \varepsilon.$$
- Your last line has an error. You'll want to be reciprocating both sides, to get $|x - 1| > \frac{3}{\varepsilon}$. Note the change in sign, as the function $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing for positive $x$.
- This means, you are looking for values of $x$ that are a greater distance than $\frac{3}{\varepsilon}$ from $1$. This suggests a that $M = 1 + \frac{3}{\varepsilon}$ is a good choice of $M$. Note that no maximums or minimums are required!
- Beware the flow of logic here! You've written in implications $\implies$ between each step. While this is true, what you really need for the definition is backwards implications: $\impliedby$. This is because you're starting with $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon$, the thing you need to conclude! This is ok, provided each step you perform **implies the previous step**, not the next step as we often tend to do. The other way is to simply rewrite the entire proof backwards, starting with assuming $x > 1 + \frac{3}{\varepsilon}$, and working logically to the desired conclusion.

EDIT: Regarding the solution you posted as an answer, it's definitely looking better, though I have a couple more pointers:

- You only really need the last block of implications. Your entire solution could be presented by simply starting with the line that begins
  $$|x - 1| > \frac{3}{\varepsilon} \iff \ldots$$
  and going from there. Sure, it doesn't explain where you got $\frac{3}{\varepsilon}$ from, but then again, it doesn't have to! The logic shows that such a choice was a good choice, no matter how you came by it.
- You still haven't come from the starting point of $x > M$, which you should, as this is part of the definition of a limit as $x \to \infty$. So, I would just add to your solution,
  \begin{align*}
  x > 1 + \frac{3}{\varepsilon} &\implies x - 1 > \frac{3}{\varepsilon} > 0 \\
  &\implies |x - 1| > \frac{3}{\varepsilon} \\
  &\implies \ldots
  \end{align*}
  Note that the above implication works because $x - 1 \ge 0$, and so $|x - 1| = x - 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Theo Bendit. I re-did my answer, not sure if it's correct.

$ |f(x) - L| = |\frac{2x+1}{1-x} +2|< \delta $

$ \qquad \quad \; \; \; =|\frac{3}{1-x} | < \delta $

$ \qquad \quad \; \; \; =|\frac{-3}{x-1} | < \delta $

$ \qquad \quad \; \; \; =|-3||\frac{1}{x-1} | < \delta $

$ \qquad \quad \; \; \; =|\frac{1}{x-1} | < \frac{\delta}{3}$

$ \qquad \quad \; \; \; =|{x-1} | > \frac{3}{\delta}$

$ \frac{3}{\delta} = \epsilon <=> \delta = \frac{3}{\epsilon}$

$ |x-1| > \frac {3}{\epsilon} <=> 0 < |\frac{1}{x-1}|<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

$\qquad \qquad \; \; <=> 0 < |\frac{3}{x-1}|<\epsilon$

$\qquad \qquad \; \; <=> 0 < |-3||\frac{1}{x-1}|<\epsilon$

$\qquad \qquad \; \; <=> 0 < |\frac{3}{1-x}|<\epsilon$

$\qquad \qquad \; \; <=> 0 < |\frac{2x+1}{1-x} + 2|<\epsilon$

$\qquad \qquad \; \; => 0 < |f(x) - L|<\epsilon$

Comment: Ok, I'M confused looking at your answer. You're overthinking this, Theo Bendit.more or less gave you an outline of the solution. Hint: Consider that $\frac {3}{\epsilon} $ > 0 for any value of x, so you can simply drop the absolute value in | x- 1| . Then just proceed with the algebra to get his suggested value of M.

Comment: Hi G.L., I've edited my answer with a bit of feedback about your answer. Hope you find it helpful.